# how to trigger modal without making use of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any better option for displaying pop-up modal on click of a button without using bootstrap. I tried few pieces of stuff but I was not able to succeed. Below I have created a sample plunker. Please let me know if there is a better option.

Comment: Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/T4dyHqcnjWwkMCCJDN0I

Comment: You will need to google it and try to do it yourself first, try searching for "how to create a pop up html, css, js"

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't to use bootstrap you can try and build a modal using Javascript and CSS. A good place to start is [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp). There is a guide on how to make create a modal box with examples you can try and edit yourself.

While your code is not far from the examples on the site the examples give nice explanations on how to style your modal and to display them siminal to the modals from bootstrap. The relevant part would be in the `.modal` css where the `z-index` is declared.

Step 3 also would add to your js code, especially this part:

```
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```